# How should I design my iPhone app's storage architecture? Small lists, dates etc

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, storage

I have an app in dev that involves a small list of people, a small list of places, and dates and times.

What is the best way to save this data?

- **People** - list will be < 30 people,
  with simple name fields and other
  small string feilds. Should i save
  them as property lists? Is there any
  way to simply create a pointer to a
  contact record instead of copying
  user data to my app and prevent it
  from going stale?
- **Dates** - What is the best way to
  manage dates with associated
  information?
- **Places** - Simple list - should I save
  this as a property list file? Same as
  people information?

Also I will be cross referencing this data so it wont be just a simple storage / retrieval of it. Any tips on achieving this sort of thing would be very helpful.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: I am aware of Core Data, but im mainly looking for tips on best practices for designing something of this nature.

Comment: Using Core Data is the best practice. Your question is a bit too vague to provide a more detailed answer.